# UCD equivalent for Groovy/Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, dead-code

In Java projects I use [UCD](http://www.ucdetector.org/) for cleaning dead/unnecessary code, and I love it.

Is there an equivalent in Groovy/Grails land?

Comment: I highly doubt it, given the dynamic nature of Groovy it would be very difficult (if at all possible) to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the highly dynamic nature of Groovy it would be very difficult (if at all possible) to do something similar to this.

I haven't seen any tools that are capable of what you are looking for and I doubt any exist for the reasons above.

Answer (score 1):

The [codenarc](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net) project (Static Analysis for Groovy) has some rules to detect [unused](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rules-unused.html) and [unnecessary](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rules-unnecessary.html)  code.